# Spark Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipeline, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to spark, can you please help in this?
The below simple pipeline to do a logistic regression produces an exception:
The Code:
    package pipeline.tutorial.com

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ParamGridBuilder
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplit

object PipelineDemo {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.set("spark.master", "local")
    conf.set("spark.app.name", "PipelineDemo")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("PipelineDemo").getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.json("C:/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master/data/simple-ml")

    val rForm = new RFormula()
    val lr = new LogisticRegression().setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("features")

    val stages = Array(rForm, lr)
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)

    val params = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(rForm.formula, Array(
      "lab ~ . + color:value1",
      "lab ~ . + color:value1 + color:value2")).addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.0, 0.5, 1.0)).addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 2.0)).build()

    val evaluator = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
.setMetricName("areaUnderROC")
.setRawPredictionCol("prediction")
.setLabelCol("label")

    val tvs = new TrainValidationSplit()
.setTrainRatio(0.75)
.setEstimatorParamMaps(params)
.setEstimator(pipeline)
.setEvaluator(evaluator)

    val Array(train, test) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
    val model = tvs.fit(train)
    val rs = model.transform(test)

    rs.select("features", "label", "prediction").show()

  }

}
```

// end code.

The code runs fine from the spark-shell
when writing it as a spark application (using eclipse scala ide) it gives the error:
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef

Thanks.

Comment: maven dependencies used:
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
   </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
   </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>

Comment: which version scala are you using? try switch to 2.12.8:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993313/not-serialazable-exception-while-running-linear-regression-scala-2-12

Comment: Thanks Boris Azanov, your hint about the scala version helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by removing scala library from the build path, to do this, right click on the scala library container > build path > remove from build path
not sure about the root cause though.

Answer (score 1):

this error can be resolved by changing the scala version in your project to 2.12.8 or higher. Scala 2.12.8 works and is very stable. You can change this by going to your project structure (In Intellij you can go by pressing 'Ctrl+alt+shift+S'). Go to Global libraries and in there you have to remove the old scala version by using the - symbol and add the new scala version i.e. 2.12.8 or higher from the + symbol.